# Piping in Windows

Tags: windows, ipc

i am have a console to controll a device driver. This tool allows me to enter numbers an change parameters of the device. Which is executed on a windows system. In order to not enter numbers manually, I am piping those numbers to the executable, like so..

```
cd %tool_path%
(
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
)myconsole.exe
```

And here is my question, is there a way to put a delay between those echos? And it would be even better if I could read the output, so I can send different numbers depandend on the output.

My idea would be writing a short programm in C or C++ doesn't matter and handle those delays in there. But I can't really find examples to this. Here is what I found.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

But in this examples I don't know where I can input `myconsole.exe`.
I also looked at named pipes, but they don't seem to be the right thing for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Unix tool called `expect` - there is a Windows version from ActiveState.

Basically, you can do things like:

```
send "Hello\r\n"
sleep 1
send "Something\r\n"
expect {
   "> " { }
   "$ " { }
}
if { $a == "soup" } {
   puts "You have soup!"
else {
   puts "No soup for you!"
}
```

There are examples [here](https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/6294378) and all over the Web - look for `Tcl/expect tutorials`.